# How to return values from a combobox and fields that it populates on a form to insert values into a new table

Tags: ms-access-2016

[image]

[image]

I can get a value into a combobox, but I can't insert the value into another table. There is a PK -> FK relationship between the two simple tables.

All I want to do is return 1 value into a combobox, the primary key from table1, and then insert the value of the primary key in the combobox into the foreign key field in table2.  I want to be able to do this using VBA so that I will be able to do the same with other values in an array in the combobox in the future.

Comment: Thank you for becoming a part of the Stackoverflow community. Could you share the Visual Basic code that you have already attempted? As it stands it appears that you are asking someone to write the code for you.

Comment: OK, it should actually be an update statement.  I am still getting a syntax error.  Here is the code:

Private Sub cboVanNumber_AfterUpdate()

 
 Dim SQL As String
 SQL = "UPDATE tblVan" & _
 "SET tblVan.FK_ID_Driver = 3" & _
 "WHERE(((tblVan.VanNumber) = [Forms]![frmRoute]![cboVanNumber]))"""
 
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL


End Sub

Comment: What I mean is, edit your original post and place the code there

Comment: If you managed to solve your problem, then post it as an **answer**. I have rolled back your edit that added a solution to the question

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the question.  Some of the names of the variables have changed.

The solution skips some steps, but solves where I was headed with a complete solution:

```
Private Sub cboVanNumber_AfterUpdate()
  
Dim ComboID As Integer
Dim strSQL As String
Dim DriverID As Integer

DriverID = Forms!frmRoute!txtDriverID
ComboID = Forms!frmRoute!cboVanNumber.Column(1)

strSQL = "UPDATE tblVan SET tblVan.FK_ID_Driver = " & DriverID & " " & vbCrLf & _
"WHERE (((tblVan.VanNumber)=" & ComboID & "));"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

End Sub
```

The solution uses the value in a textbox, DriverID, which is the foreign key in tblVan. The foreign key is updated in the table after a VanNumber is chosen from a combobox that relates to the foreign key. Basically, I reversed the order of updating to the textbox, instead of using the combobox. Additionally, the VanNumber is not the primary key, but it is uniquely related to the primary key.